# g++ linker options changes target file name

Tags: compilation, linker, g++

I need help it is bug or I don't understand how compilation options are working ?
I have sample main.c file and try to compile it as:

```
$ g++ -nostdlib -g -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -ffreestanding -nostdinc -nostdinc++ -Wl,--build-id=none,-g,-nostdlib,-nostartfiles,-zmax-page-size=0x1000 main.c -o main
```

and as output I have this:

```
$ ls
main.c  startfiles
```

I am trying to understand why g++ created file named "startfiles" not "main" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [GNU `ld` official documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.24/ld/Options.html#Options) you will see that there is no option named `-nostartfiles`. What you *do* pass for arguments to the linker with that is the options `-n` and `-ostartfiles`.

If I were you, I would check those other options you try to pass to the linker as well.

Answer (score 0):

`-nostartfiles` is a compiler flag as far as I know, not a linker flag.

For the linker, it's the same as `-n -o startfiles`, which is why you're getting that output file name.